# Does the return of the laravel return json by default?

Tags: php, laravel

i want to that //Does the return of the laravel return json by default?

```
return $result;
```

Comment: What is the type of $result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If you return an object in a Laravel controller, it will serialize the object to a JSON string.

If you would return a string, the raw string will be returned.

More info on responses: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/responses#creating-responses

Answer (score 0):

It returns JSON if you're returning from an ajax request made by AXIOS or similar.  If you're returning from a web request, unless you have specified for the request to be JSON, it will be whatever you are sending back, ie, and Object if it's a model, or an array, or collection etc.